# InsertMany() gives FormatException, my attempt at handling it results in duplicate key error

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a function for inserting a list of entries into my MongoDB database, like so:

```
public static void TraceDatabaseInsert(string collection, List<BsonDocument> posts)
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("TraceDatabase");

        var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);

        try
        {
            coll.InsertMany(posts);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            if (posts.Count == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Trace to large to enter into database");
            }
            else
            {
                var postsList = SplitList(posts);
                foreach (var entries in postsList)
                {
                    coll.InsertMany(entries);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

On rare occasions, the posts is to large to insert in one go and throws a FormatException, so a made a function for splitting the post in two:

```
public static List<List<BsonDocument>> SplitList(List<BsonDocument> list)
    {
        var firstHalf = (int)Math.Ceiling(list.Count / 2.0);
        var secondHalf = list.Count - firstHalf;
        var returnList = new List<List<BsonDocument>>();
        returnList.Add(list.GetRange(0, firstHalf));
        returnList.Add(list.GetRange(firstHalf, secondHalf));

        return returnList;
    }
```

However, when i try to insert the split lists, I get a MongoBulkWriteException in the form of E11000 duplicate key error.

Is this due to the initial operation inserting some documents before throwing the exception, so that I'm actually trying to insert duplicates? Does anyone know  way of getting around this?

Otherwise, what could be the cause?

EDIT: [Here's an image of the local variables at the time of the exception being thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8gSo.png)

Comment: posts.Count comes in at, in this case, 189, with the new lists containing 95 and 94 posts, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

What is almost certainly happening is the first call to `InsertMany` is inserting *some* of the records. As per [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/):

> Note that one document was inserted: The first document of _id: 13
>   will insert successfully, but the second insert will fail. This will
>   also stop additional documents left in the queue from being inserted.

Then you try inserting them all again (inside the `catch`). This then fails, since *some* of them were inserted in the first `InsertMany` call.

You may want to consider using [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/). Or, as you highlight in the comments, set `Ordered` to `false` so that:

> Excluding Write Concern errors, ordered operations stop after an
>   error, while unordered operations **continue to process** any
>   remaining write operations in the queue.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like I could get away with setting "Ordered" to false and it would simply skip the duplicate documents. Do you think that might cause unexpected issues?

Comment: Seems to work, however it did reveal that my "solution" to the initial problem of the insert failing due to size isn't fixed. So that's gonna take some more debugging. Thanks for the help, though!